# UNIX subtraction of comma separated number

Tags: shell

Seeking help to understand if there is any shell change or how this works.. we use ksh.

I executed a command 1 day and got `a=12,345,789; b=200; echo $(($a-$b))` as `589` but after couple of weeks the same command returned actual subtracted value i.e. `12345589`.

Thanks

Comment: 1. add the ksh version you use, please

Comment: 2. 1 day means like what exactly?

Comment: on a particular day, I meant.. ksh version is sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01. Also the same command was executed on same machine

Answer (score 3):

The interpretation of `12,345,789` in ksh seems to depend on the locale:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=C ksh -c 'a=12,345,789; b=200; echo $(($a-$b))'
589
$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 ksh -c 'a=12,345,789; b=200; echo $(($a-$b))'
12345589
```

In the C locale, it's the three numbers `12`, `345`, and `789` separated by the comma operator, which basically just throws away all but the rightmost value. Apparently, in the `en_US.UTF-8` locale on my machine, the comma acts as a thousands separator, so it's the single number `12345789` instead.

On the other hand, in the `fi_FI.UTF-8` locale that input causes the error "ksh: 12,345,789-200: arithmetic syntax error", but removing one comma makes the number get accepted, this time as a decimal separator:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=fi_FI.UTF-8 ksh -c 'a=12,345; b=200; echo $(($a - $b))'
-187,655
```

Note that e.g. Bash doesn't appear to interpret the numbers based on locale, so the commas always get interpreted as comma operators.

Comment: Here, one may want to do `printf '%,ld\n' "${a//,} - ${b//,}"` or `printf "%ld\n" "${a//,} - ${b//,}"` depending on whether one wants the thousands separators (locale dependant) on output or not (and removing `,` from input, whether or not they're the locale's thousand separator)